# Will JVM choose the best GC type on its own during runtime?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

JVM up from java 11 is using by Default G1.

If i wont change anything by myself, will JVM make any improvements by it own and change for example to Serial if my app will be lacking resources. Or whether app is in the container or not?
Or i have to manage it by myself?

Comment: The JVM uses some heuristics to pick a GC algorithm for the current environment. This, however, doesn’t imply that the choice will always be “the best” for your use case, as the JVM can’t know what’s your actual goal (e.g. best overall execution time, lowest latency, or lowest memory consumption), nor how the application you just started will behave over time.

Answer (score 0):

No you will have to manage it yourself.

The default one Garbage First (G1) is a Solution that works good on most (almost all) cases. Finetuning or switching the GC is possible, but do so only with great care. You can easily make it worse, so only touch it if you really have a problem nailed down to the GC